# Как сравнить 2 аудио файла, возвращая процент разницы

Tags: c#, java, аудио, c++

Есть ли способ, чтобы сравнить 2 аудио-файлы, в результате чего процент от разницы будут возвращены? чтобы сравнить звук (не только файлы) в 2 аудио файлы с теми же свойствами и тот же формат (WAV), и показать, разница в процентах между 2 звуки в 2 аудио файлов. можно на любом язык программирования.

Comment: Задачка интересная. Мне это напомнило идентификацию подводных лодок.

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю такой способ. Вначале строим "изображение сигнала", например, как описано [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/113239/) (В сети гуляет много вариантов кода). Теперь задача сводиться к сравнению двух картинок.

На самом деле график строить не нужно, можно сравнить в памяти, просто, если представить в виде картинки, легче понять алгоритм.

Но по ходу дела могут подстерегать следующие трудности:

- разная амплитуда. Но это легко исправляется.  Называется нормирование. Рассчитываем сраднее (но только значений по модулю!, а то среднее может быть равным нулю), а потом просто домножаем значения на рассчитанный коефициент.
- погрешности. То, что на слух идентично, на картинке может выглядеть достаточно разным. Поэтому не стоит сравнивать на равенство, а где то так `abs(a1 - a2) < e1`, где abs - модуль, a1 и а2 две амплитуды. Значение е1 подбирается экспериментально.
- свиг.

Как я бы решал эту задачу. 
 - Вначале вычитал два файла.
 - Сделал ресемлинг  (понижение частоты). По факту - просто подсчитывал среднее квадратичное за каждые десятые секунды. В результате минутный файл будет занимать массив на 600 целых. 
 - Следующим этапом - нормализировал (так как у нас среднеквадратичное, то все значения положительные, то просто ищем максимум. Потом все значения домножаем на 256/максимум. вместо 256 можно подставить свое любимое значение).
 - теперь просто сравниваем два массива. Если предполагаем, что есть свиги, то применяем классические алгоритмы поиска подстроки в строке.

Понятное дело, что бы алгоритм был достаточно интеллектуальным, придется хорошо потрудиться.

Comment: А если отличается скорость проигрывания файлов? Ну, скажем, один файл был записан с x1, а второй - с x0.99. Ясно, что они будут разные. Но при этом содержимое одинаковое. Вообще судя по всему анализ (сравнение) звука и видео - задача не самая простая.

Comment: В целом - можно и это обойти. Например так. Считаем кол-во пиков (или "волн"). Дальше в каждом наборе отсчитываем какое-то кол-во этих пиков. Теперь можно нормализировать по времени. После этого можно сравнить.

Comment: Хм. Оценка несовпадения картинок мне не кажется релевантной для задачи. Надо бы вычленить частотный спектр (фурье?), перевести в ноты, и определить, насколько отличаются длительности. Мороки огого.

Comment: ноты говорите? а уверены, что их всегда можно "выделить"?

А вот анализ с учетом частотного спектра имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: @KoVadim: конечно, не всегда, белый шум есть белый шум. А выделять ноты мне приходилось, там надо было не забыть гармоники приплюсовать к нотам, а не считать за отдельную ноту. Попробуйте сами, это не так сложно! Зато можно будет определять что-нибудь типа "это та же мелодия, но сыграна без мелизмов". :)

Answer (score 3):

Тк, нужно сравнивать не только файлы но и звук, то из задачи становится что без частотного анализа здесь не обойтись.
Я бы попробовал следующее. Логически дискретм отрывок звука (например берем все частоты появившиеся за  100мс, чем чаще тем лучше), строим качественное FFT и сохраняем массив частот. Берем второй отрывок и делаем тоже самое и сравниваем. Попал нипопал сравниваем в %.

Вопрос синхронизации отрывков, берем из первого кусок, смотрим есть ли такой же во втором.
Вопрос скорости проигрывания, при изменении скорости проигрывания частоты звуков также повышаются. Разница в отрывке между оригиналом и ускоренным будет как правило константа.

Comment: Угу, причём частоты тоже могут совпадать приблизительно, и для каждого участка надо искать сходство в общей структуре спектрограммы, а не сравнивать досконально каждую частоту. Например, можно с определённым шагом построить последовательность пиков и сравнивать местоположение, а также интенсивность максимумов и провалов.